# Oracle not raising exceptions

Tags: database, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I am making a function that receives a client id and an animal id, then it needs to verify if that animal belongs to that client, if so, it searches on the appointments table to get the number of appointments for that animal.

I believe ORACLE is not raising my exceptions... The code is below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CalcNrConsultas (idani IN number, idcli IN number) return number 
IS 

teste EXCEPTION;
AniNaoPertenceCli EXCEPTION;
qtd number;
t_animal Animal.IdAnimal%type;
t_cliente Animal.IDCliente%type;

BEGIN
  SELECT IDAnimal, IDCliente INTO t_animal, t_cliente FROM Animal 
  WHERE IDAnimal = idani AND IDCliente = idcli;
IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
    RAISE AniNaoPertenceCli;
ELSE
    SELECT COUNT(Consulta.IDAnimal) INTO qtd FROM Consulta INNER JOIN Animal ON Consulta.IdAnimal = Animal.IdAnimal
    WHERE (Consulta.IDAnimal = idani) AND (Animal.IDAnimal = idani AND Animal.IDCliente = idcli);
    IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
        RAISE teste;
    END IF;
END IF;
return qtd;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN AniNaoPertenceCli THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('O animal escolhido não pertence ao cliente indicado, logo não pode fazer esta consulta.');
  WHEN teste THEN 
    dbms_output.put_line('O animal indicado não efetuou nenhuma consulta.');
END;
/
```

Comment: Why do you say it's not raising exceptions? if you remove the exception handling block, or add a raise after the put_line do you get an exception or not?

Comment: @Aleksej because I tried with different inputs and didnt receive the output I should have.

i am trying with this code: 
SELECT CalcNrConsultas(3, 1) AS "Número de Consultas:" FROM dual;

Comment: Try to add a raise after the call to putline and see what happens

Comment: @Aleksej You mean this:
WHEN teste THEN 
        dbms_output.put_line('O animal indicado não efetuou nenhuma consulta.');
        RAISE AniNaoPertenceCli;
?

Comment: Yes. If you get an exception, the issue is simply that you have to set your client to show the dbms_output.

Comment: @Aleksej Oh but that is not the issue, because I have just made other functions that use the dbms_output and it shows, its something else..

Comment: Sorry, I paid not enough attention to your code; you seem to have a different issue , see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the way you handle the case in which the select queries give no result: you need to use a block with some exception handling to catch the case when a query gives no result.

For example, this will not catch the exception:

```
SQL> declare
  2      x number;
  3  begin
  4      select 1
  5      into x
  6      from dual where 1 = 2;
  7      --
  8      if sql%notfound then
  9          dbms_output.put_line('sql%notfound');
 10      end if;
 11      --
 12      dbms_output.put_line('Found');
 13  end;
 14  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

But this will:

```
SQL> declare
  2      x number;
  3  begin
  4      begin
  5          select 1
  6          into x
  7          from dual where 1 = 2;
  8      exception
  9          when NO_DATA_FOUND then
 10              x := null;
 11              dbms_output.put_line('NOT FOUND');
 12      end;
 13      --
 14      if x is not null then
 15          dbms_output.put_line('Found');
 16      end if;
 17  end;
 18  /
NOT FOUND
```

Also, a `count(...)` will not give `NO_DATA_FOUND`, but the result 0:

```
SQL> select count(1)
  2  from dual
  3  where 1 = 2;

  COUNT(1)
----------
         0
```

So to check the result of the second query, you have to check the value of the variable `qtd`.

Comment: Ok I have done what you said, it is now halfway done.
The first part where is checks if the animal belongs to the client, I did as you said, and its working.
Although the other part, (the count one) is not working, it keeps sending me to the "no_data_found" exception, instead of sending me to the "teste" exception..